# how to move the uploaded files to archive folder using java code

Tags: java

```
public class Upload extends HttpServlet 
{

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       public void init() throws ServletException
       {

               System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
       }

       protected  void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
       {
               //boolean MultipartRequest;
       //String PrintWriter;

               response.setContentType("text/html");

               PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
               MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request,"/home/hadoop/Desktop");

              out.println("succcesfully uploaded");

       }
       public void  destroy()
       {
               System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
       }

}
```

- what i need to do to move the files uploded to the Desktop folder
  directly  instead of giving the file name directly as below
- and one more is how to copy duplicates too...

```
public class MoveFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File sourceFile = new File("/home/hadoop/Desktop/LINUX-KACPER.pdf");
        File destinationDir = new File("/home/hadoop/Documents/movedfiles/");

        FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destinationDir, true);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is moving file with timemill....

```
public class Moveall {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File destinationDir = new File("/home/hadoop/Documents/movedfiles/");
    File directory = new File("/home/hadoop/Desktop/");
    File[] subfiles = directory.listFiles();
    for(File f:subfiles){
    FileUtils.moveFile(f,new File(destinationDir.getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+f.getName()));
    System.out.println("moved succesfully....");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, it it is the answer:

```
public class MoveFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File destinationDir = new File("/home/hadoop/Documents/movedfiles/");
        File directrory = new File("/home/hadoop/Desktop/");
        File[] subfiles = directory.listFiles();
        for(File f:subfiles){
            new File(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()+f.getName()).delete() //remove the duplicate
            FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(f, destinationDir, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will pick all files on desktop and move them to movedfiles
You can use FileFilter as a parameter of listFiles
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)

EDIT (versions):

```
public class MoveFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File destinationDir = new File("/home/hadoop/Documents/movedfiles/");
        File directrory = new File("/home/hadoop/Desktop/");
        File[] subfiles = directory.listFiles();
        for(File f:subfiles){
            File previous = new File(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()+f.getName())
            if(!previous.exists()){
                FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(f, destinationDir, true);
            }else{
                FileUtils.moveFile(f,new File(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+f.getName()), true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: writed by javadoc, not tested.
The method
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()
Is the first thing how you can make a versions, surely it can be solved with
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()
But this is only simple example

Comment: thnk u @maskacovnik it was working but i need to copy the duplicate values too can u please help me

Comment: I dont know what you mean with duplicate values..., Do you mean rewriting the files, or do you mean subfolders too? If you mean rewriting, just to delete the file, where the new one will be pasted. I have updated my source code, but it is not tested @nani

Comment: sorry not duplicate values its duplicate files i mean two files with the same name and data

Comment: I don't know what you mean, you cant have two files with same name in one folder... @nani

Comment: Sorry! The above upload file code is going to run on server, if any two are uploading their files having same name also be moved to the another folder. i think here time stamp is used to change the file name with the time stamp. but i don't have an idea on time stamp..

Comment: I have understood it. So you upoad same file more times and you want to have something like backups or versions in movedfiles? @nani

Comment: yes exactly as you said. But this code is not moving the duplicates. @maskacovnik

Comment: So try to use control `println()` to figure it out. Try to `println()` in if and else the paths of destination files.

Comment: thanks for ur help @maskacovnik the code is working with few edits i did it and post the answer.

Comment: Can u plz send me ur mail id. my mail id is coupons998@gmail.com @maskacovnik